# Generate YAML schema or models for Doctrine from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Is it somehow possible to automatically generate a YAML schema file or models from an existing MySQL database?

I need to create models for Doctrine but writing the model classes manually seems extremely boring to me. I already have MySQL database with tables and all relations so it would help me if there is some way to generate Doctrine models from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using doctrine 2:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible ;-)

For Doctrine 1.2, take a look at the [**Command Line Interface**](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/utilities/en#command-line-interface) : amongst other utilities, you have the possibity to generate the YAML files from an existing database.

And, for Doctrine 2.0, you'll want to take a look at [**Reverse Engineering**](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering)